# JavaBean Introspection with Optional return types

Tags: java, javabeans, guava, option-type, introspection

```
java.beans.Introspector#getBeanInfo
```

compiles an incomplete `PropertyDescriptor` when changing the getter return type to `com.google.common.base.Optional`.

I'm using Java 7 and thus have to use Guava's `Optional`. I'd like to use it as return types in my JavaBeans.
I've prepared these two small unit tests to outline the problem:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;    
import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;    
import org.junit.Test;    
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

public class BeanOptionalTest {

  class SimpleBean {
    private String foo;
    public String getFoo() { return foo; }
    public void setFoo(String foo) { this.foo = foo; }
  }

  @Test
  public void test_SimpleBean() throws Exception {
    assertFooProperty(SimpleBean.class);
  }

  class OptionalBean {
    private String foo;
    public Optional<String> getFoo() { return Optional.fromNullable(foo); }
    public void setFoo(String foo) { this.foo = foo; }
  }

  @Test
  public void test_OptionalBean() throws Exception {
    assertFooProperty(OptionalBean.class);
  }

  private void assertFooProperty(Class<?> beanClass) throws IntrospectionException {
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(beanClass);
    assertEquals(2, beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors().length);
    PropertyDescriptor fooDescriptor = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()[1];
    assertNotNull(fooDescriptor.getReadMethod());
    assertEquals("getFoo", fooDescriptor.getReadMethod().getName());
    assertNotNull(fooDescriptor.getWriteMethod());
    assertEquals("setFoo", fooDescriptor.getWriteMethod().getName());
  }
}
```

`test_OptionalBean` fails because the write method is `null`. Presumably the Introspector matches foo to the type `Optional` instead of `String`.

How can this behaviour be changed in order to receive a complete `PropertyDescriptor` despite changing the return type to `Optional`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test breaks because the type of the parameter of `OptionalBean::setFoo` doesn't match the return type of `OptionalBean::getFoo`. A `PropertyDescriptor` is specific to a type and here, `Optional<String>` and `String` are not the same type, even if conceptually they are strongly linked.

With the current implementation of JavaBeans, you can't do what you want to do. What you *could* do is write your own `BeanInfo`-like object that does the introspection for you but doesn't implement `BeanInfo`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I was hoping for an easier solution or some extension point of the Introspector, but apparently I have to go all the way.